# return disposable depending on parent disposable

Tags: c#, dispose, using, system.io.compression

Here is part of the code i am working on (modified for clarity):

```
public Stream getMyArchiveStream(string archivepath)
{
    using(var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(_filepath))
    {
        var entry = archive.GetEntry(archivepath);
        return entry.Open();
    }
}

public void useMyArchiveStream()
{
    using(var myStream = getMyArchiveStream("test.path"))
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Now this fails, because *archive* is being disposed at the exit of *getMyArchiveStream* which prevents usage of *myStream*.

**Is there a way to dispose of *archive* when *myStream* is being disposed of?**

The alternative is to leave *archive* open and make the containing class disposable, but that has it's own drawbacks in usability.

Background:

I created a simple packaging class (Simpler that System.IO.Packaging at least) that returns the files as byte arrays. Obviously that consumes a lot of memory and i want to use streams instead.

Comment: Rather than having `useMyArchiveStream` call `getMyArchiveStream`, pass `useMyArchiveStream` as a `Func` to `getMyArchiveStream` so that the second `using` occurs **inside** (rather than separate to) the first `using`.

Comment: Alternatively, have `getMyArchiveStream` return a `Tuple` and let `useMyArchiveStream` take care of disposing both properties of the `Tuple`.

Comment: Did either of those option work @DerMaggi?

Comment: I have to test those when i am back from work, but i rather like the first idea. With a wrapper function that may exactly what i need. I will post an appropiate update as soon as i have tested that @mjwills

Comment: @mjwills I am using the first method now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, you're taking shortcuts you just can't take. As your question title already literally says, you're trying to use an object that *depends* on an object you dispose.

What you are trying to do is open a file, read some *information* about its internals from it (not the actual internals themselves), *then* close the file, and *then* try to use that information to actually read from that file. It's impossible; *the file is already closed.* Just like you can't return a disposable object from inside its own `using` block without ending up with a disposed and thus unusable object, you obviously also can't return something that *depends* on the disposable object.

So, basically, the whole thought process behind your `getMyArchiveStream` function is flawed. You should not have that function at all. You just need to make the other function like this:

```
public void UseMyArchiveStream()
{
    using(var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(_filepath))
    {
        var entry = archive.GetEntry("test.path");
        using(var myStream = entry.Open())
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

One alternative is indeed to leave `archive` open... but as [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) commented, there is another way to do what you want, and that's to give `UseMyArchiveStream` an `Action<>` or `Func<>` as argument. This literally means that the "Do stuff" comment in the code above is replaced by a call to whatever function you give as argument:

```
public void UseMyArchiveStream(String zipPath, String entryName, Action<Stream, String> doStuff)
{
    using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
    {
        var entry = archive.GetEntry(entryName);
        using (var myStream = entry.Open())
        {
            doStuff(myStream, entry.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Demonstrated with a function `void SaveStreamToFile(Stream file, String filename)`:

```
UseMyArchiveStream(_filepath, "test.path", (str, nm) => SaveStreamToFile(str, nm));
```

With `Func<>`, you can make an overload that gives a return value too. The last argument inside the `<>` is always the return type. But you can easily use generics to make that depend on the calling input:

```
public T UseMyArchiveStream<T>(String zipPath, String entryName, Func<Stream, String, T> doStuff)
{
    using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
    {
        var entry = archive.GetEntry(entryName);
        using (var myStream = entry.Open())
        {
            return doStuff(myStream, entry.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

You can call this the same way, only with a function that returns a value rather than `void`. Demonstrated with `Boolean DostuffWithFile(Stream file, String entryName)`:

```
Boolean ok = UseMyArchiveStream(_filepath, "test.path", (str, nm) => DostuffWithFile(str, nm));
```

Note that the function you call does not have to match the exact signature of the argument. You can perfectly substitute missing arguments with local data in this way of calling.

Demonstrated with `Boolean DostuffWithFile(Stream file, String entryName, Boolean someOption, String outputFolder)`:

```
Boolean ok = UseMyArchiveStream(_filepath, "test.path", (str, nm) => DostuffWithFile(str, nm, true, _savePath));
```

This will work as long as the input that needs to be provided by `UseMyArchiveStream` is just the part before the `=>`. Of course, you can juggle the arguments however you want; you can even just give the function the whole `ZipArchiveEntry` object, and perhaps even the source `ZipFile`, so you can do whatever you want with it.

The only disadvantage to this approach is that you can't actually name the components of the `Action<>` or `Func<>`, so, in this case, you can't know from just the function signature of `UseMyArchiveStream` whether that `String` argument given to `Func<Stream, String, T>` will receive the `entry.Name` or the `entry.FullName`. The same applies to giving multiple arguments of the same type; if you have five boolean options in that `Func<>` you may have a hard time remembering exactly which is which without having to look into the code each time. So be sure to accurately document that in the function comments, to avoid confusion later.

Comment: This really clears up mjwills suggestion, and suits my purpose well

Answer (score -1):

It is important to understand why dispose is called so you know when you have to call it and when not. [Dispose and Finalize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) are strongly related.

Finalize is all about making certain that Unmanaged resources (Filehandles, Networkhandles, Natively Adressed Memory Space) can be released by the GC. But while it is sure that the GC **will** run, it is not determinsitic **when** it will do so. Indeed if it only runs at application closure, that is the ideal case that most implementations aim for.

Dispose is all about making sure that Finalisation is Deterministic. When you dispose you do not Finalize anymore. You do the job of Finalization early. You do it when you it want, rather then when the GC will get around to it.

There are many details, but for me it boils down to there being two cases where you implement IDisposeable:
 * You handle unmanaged resoruce directly. In thise case you make Finalisation first. Then Dispose as a convenience/useability feature. You will not really run into thise case, as most are taken care off by the Framework programmers.
 * You handle any class that implements IDisposeable, for the sole purpose to "relay" the Dispose call to all cotained instances. Easily 95% of all Disposeable calls are about that.

With ZipArchive my guess is the main reason it implements IDisposeable, is because of the filehandle it has to contain. And Entry might just implement it because it holds a Reference to the ZipArchive instance. And it should thus relay the call. While it is possible there is something else in ZipArchiveEntry that needs disposing, I think it is unlikely. So you should be able to cut out that using, as long as you make certain the ZipArchive instance is properly disposed.

Comment: I agree, that the disposable stems from using a file handle. However i dont want to return the ZipArchive stream as i aim to make the consumptions as easy and none verbose as reasonably possible. And that is returning the stream from the entry.